# I can't properly convert string to Int in C#

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, int

The type conversion doesn't function as expected

I broke down the problem but it still occurs

```
string a = "123";

int i = Convert.ToInt32(a[0]);

Console.WriteLine(i);
```

I expect the result of 1 but I get 49. I can't imagine how.

Comment: `int i = Convert.ToInt32(a.Substring(0, 1));`

Comment: `int i = a[0] - '0';` for single digit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do the indexer `a[0]` you get a `char` which for `1` is char code number 49. Do `Convert.ToInt32(a[0].ToString())` or subtract 48 from the result you get instead to get the numerical representation.

Comment: But i want to use it as an intieger for claculations !     Edit: ok i got it thanks i used Convert.ToInt32(a[0].ToString());

Comment: you could use `.ToString()` or just subtract 48.